# How to create a table in sqlite3 with column names taken from a list?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, multiple-columns

I intend to create a table in sqlite3 with the column names in a list [item1,...]. I don't want to hard code the column names while creating the table because the number of columns and even names are dynamic. I want the correct syntax to get the column names directly from this list. Thank you. I'm using python.

Comment: You may also need to specify the type of each column. Are they of the same type?

Comment: Yes all the columns are  of the same data type- TEXT

Comment: Sorry the data type is REAL

Comment: In addition to this I will also like to get the syntax to insert values into this columns using a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import contextlib
import sqlite3

fields = ["field1", "field2", "field3"]

with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(':memory:')) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    columns = ", ".join("{field} TEXT".format(field=field) for field in fields)
    cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS your_table(
         id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
         {columns}
    )
    """.format(columns=columns))
    conn.commit()
```

But, you should consider using an ORM, like SqlAlchemy. Here is a tutorial for that: https://www.pythoncentral.io/introductory-tutorial-python-sqlalchemy/

**Edit**

To go further, your insert statement could be built like this:

```
stmt = ("INSERT INTO mytable ({fields}) VALUES ({marks})"
.format(fields=", ".join(fields), marks=", ".join("?" * len(fields))))
```

For instance:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Thank you Laurent,  This nailed it!!!!!   How can I do the same thing for INSERT values. My values to be inserted in the colums are also in a list. Ive tried "INSERT INTO mytable ({col}) VALUES (?)",format (col=mycollist), (",".join ({x}"(x=x for x in myvaluelist))  but it's not working.

Comment: SO is not a development service. You should really look around for some tutorials and play with it. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a million!!!!!. Whew, finaly got it. Laurent, just as you know these are not common place questions and answers. One must be trying to solve a unique problem to hit such brick wall. I have done a lot of researches on the internet to get answers to but to no avail. You just that problem. THANK YOU FOR RELIEVING ME OF SLEEPLESS NIGHTS.LOL